# Is there a way to restrict folder browsing in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRtME1oJD7M) and I made a file browser, Is there a way to restrict people browsing outside a certain folder, eg. C:\Folder\Folder2
and that you cannot browse past folder 2, also that you can hide the parts before so that only the folder name (folder2) displays?

I have tried to make it an if statement in the go button, so

```
if(FilePathTxtBx.Contains(@"Folder2\")) 
{
    //continues navigation
    [...]
}
else 
{
    FilePathTxtBx.Text="";
    MessageBox.Show("Error: File path not found");
}
```

Although it sort of work, the code has many flaws where if you create a directory outside it with the files title it will still navigate there.

Edit: I have edited my code to the suggestions from the comments, it works with no problem.

Comment: If you only want to be able to browse inside `C:\Folder\Folder2` why not use the whole path in your if-condition and use [String.StartsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: if(FilePathTxtBx.Text.StartWith("C:\Folder\Folder2"))

Comment: There wouldn't be much point since a user can browse anything on the file system that they have access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Change if statement to Text.StartsWith, to strip the text simply take out the C:[...] by replacing the text with nothing.